# how to set regex to accept values between 0.1 and 100 iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, regex

Hi all I need a REGEX which can accept values between 0.1 and 100 while entering values in textfield.

I do have figuredout some of the REGEX but it does not work

```
^[.1-100]+([.][0-100]{0,3})?$
```

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,5})?$
```

but it's not working as expected, Please hep to figure it out.

Comment: Try [`^(?:100|0[.][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?(?:[.][0-9])?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/Psc1cI/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be easier to

- explicitly exclude 0 using `^(?!0$)`,
- explicitly exclude anything less than 0.1 using `^(?!0?0\.0)` and also
- explicitly include 100.

The rest is just any two-digit number with optional decimal part (up to 5 digits):

```
^(?!0$)(?!0?0\.0)(?:100|\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,5})?)$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Di2l1l/6

Comment: It shouldn't match `00.0025` I think.

Comment: @V.V, yes, you're right. Missed that too. Please see the updated answer.